# Why does LWP fail to connect with "500 SSL negotiation failed"?

Tags: perl, openssl, centos, lwp

My Perl script sends some information to a remote server.

Below is a portion of the code

```perl
#!/var/hvmail/libexec/perl

use strict;

use HTTP::Request::Common qw(POST);
use LWP::UserAgent;

use constant HANDLER_URL => "https://www.website.com/handler.php";

$ENV{HTTPS_DEBUG} = 1;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

# Some DB stuff, not applicable
my $row; # This is a DB row ($sth->fetchrow_hashref())   

my $req = POST ''.HANDLER_URL, [ %$row ]; 
my $res = $ua->request($req);
```

`$res->is_success` is *false* with `$res->status_line` being

```
500 SSL negotiation failed
```

We are running CentOS 6.4, Perl 5.10.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips.

#### Update

Here's the full output:

```
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
SSL3 alert read:fatal:handshake failure
SSL_connect:error in SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client hello A
SSL3 alert read:fatal:handshake failure
SSL_connect:failed in SSLv3 read server hello A
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv2 write client hello A
SSL_connect:failed in SSLv2 read server hello A
Error: [ 500 SSL negotiation failed:  ]
```

#### Requested Command Output

```
Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm
Can't locate LWP/Protocol/https.pm
```

Comment: `use warnings 'all'` should *always* accompany `use strict`

Comment: I added use warnings 'all'; but it doesn't change the output.

Comment: No, it probably wouldn't. That's why I wrote a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: I explained what I believe is the simplest way for you to install the required packages and their dependencies. Bear in mind that there is some risk involved in this, so make sure you have a way to undo the changes before you attempt it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be relying on [Crypt::SSLeay](https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::SSLeay). You shouldn't. It's outdated and incomplete.

Install the latest [LWP::Protocol::https](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Protocol::https) which will upgrade your LWP and install the preferred SSL/TLS stack consisting of the [IO::Socket::SSL](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::SSL) and [Net::SSLeay](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSLeay).

A [web search shows](https://altlinux.pkgs.org/sisyphus/classic-noarch/perl-LWP-Protocol-https-6.07-alt1.noarch.rpm.html) there are CentOS6 repositories with RPM packages for `LWP::Protocol::https`.

The server has disabled SSLv3 support which means the negotiation fails.

Once you install the package, if you are still seeing the same error, make sure your script is not forcing the use of `Crypt::SSLeay`. That is, make sure none of the following appears anywhere in your script:

```
use Net::HTTPS;
$Net::HTTPS::SSL_SOCKET_CLASS = 'Net::SSL';
```

or

```
local $ENV{PERL_NET_HTTPS_SSL_SOCKET_CLASS} = 'Net::SSL';
```

or

```
use Net::SSL;
```

If you are still running into problems, make sure there is no `PERL_NET_HTTPS_SSL_SOCKET_CLASS` environment variable in the script's run time environment.

Also, try

```
$ /var/hvmail/libexec/perl -MNet::SSLeay -le 'print $Net::SSLeay::VERSION'
```

and

```
$ /var/hvmail/libexec/perl -MLWP::Protocol::https -le 'print $LWP::Protocol::https::VERSION`'
```

and report the output.

I suspect the issue is that the new packages were installed for the system's `perl` whereas it seems you may have a separate `perl`.

If that is the case, you should install each package individually using `/var/hvmail/libexec/perl`. For example:

```
$ curl -O https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/M/MI/MIYAGAWA/App-cpanminus-1.7043.tar.gz
$ tar xvf App-cpanminus-1.7043.tar.gz
$ cd App-cpanminus-1.7043
$ /var/hvmail/libexec/perl Makefile.PL
$ make install
```

Figure out where `cpanm` was installed. I am hoping `/var/hvmail/libexec`.

```
$ /var/hvmail/libexec/cpanm LWP::Protocol::https
```

See also [Updating all outdated Perl modules](https://www.nu42.com/2012/05/updating-all-outdated-perl-modules.html), but that may be risky on a production. Still, installing [App::cpanoutdated](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::cpanoutdated), and seeing how outdated your Perl modules are might be useful

Now, keep in mind that tinkering with a production install like this is risky. Make sure you have a way to undo changes in case something goes wrong.

Finally, note that [OpenSSL 1.0.1 versions are no longer supported](https://www.openssl.org/policies/releasestrat.html):

> With regards to current and future releases the OpenSSL project has adopted the following policy:
>
> - Version 1.1.0 will be supported until 2018-08-31.
> - Version 1.0.2 will be supported until 2019-12-31 (LTS).
> - Version 1.0.1 is no longer supported.
> - Version 1.0.0 is no longer supported.
> - Version 0.9.8 is no longer supported.

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't caught up with that.

Comment: @Borodin I am familiar with the debug messages as I maintain that package in a state of coma ;-)

Comment: @Dbl0McJim: *FnG* is inappropriate here. Please be more careful with your language. How do you think that first clause improved you post?

Comment: lol, sorry for the language - meant nothing by it. Though I believe I was able to install the package, including dependencies without error. However, nothing changes with the output of the command. Do I have to "use" this package specifically? Or update any other perl modules so that this new module is used? Thanks

Comment: The script might be forcing `LWP` to use `Crypt::SSLeay` by using one of [these methods](https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::SSLeay#DO-YOU-NEED-Crypt::SSLeay?) ... Make sure none of those three methods is being used in the script.

Comment: I'm not seeing those, the use statements mentioned above are the only ones included in the script.

Comment: @Dbl0McJim: according to http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/ CentOS 6 comes  with an old version of LWP (5.833) which still defaults to Crypt::SSLeay. Better upgrade the LWP version too.

Comment: @SinanÜnür, you're correct, it does not use the system perl. Is there any way to copy over those newly installed libraries?

Comment: @Dbl0McJim: Please don't *lol* at us. It is you who is the foolish one.

Comment: @SinanÜnür, thank you for all the info. I was able to use cpan to install the newer modules, and included the library path in the script, so it used the newer version. I had to include use IO::Socket::SSL to get it to actually use TLS, but it worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Dbl0McJim You are welcome, but you shouldn't have to `use IO::Socket::SSL` explicitly. That indicates a problem you should look into. Glad the upgrade went OK.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for `''.HANDLER_URL`. It looks ugly, and `HANDLER_URL` is fine

You don't explain what is in `$row` or what the `POST` call requires, but it looks like this

```
my $req = POST ''.HANDLER_URL, [ %$row ]; 
my $res = $ua->request($req);
```

should be

```
my $res = $ua->post(HANDLER_URL, $row);
```